# How to instantiate and reuse services in PHP

Tags: php

In Java EE, I would use Spring to instantiate and reuse my services. Now I've created a small framework in PHP to support my application, using services, repositories and DAOs.

However, how can I instantiate, but more importantly, re-use these objects, without having to instantiate a new object every time?

It's tempting to just start using singletons, but then my code would turn into a mess pretty quickly.

In fact, I'm having trouble with using good OO practices and design patterns with PHP in general. Is there any good resource on this?

Comment: I liked this book on PHP Design Patterns: http://www.amazon.com/PHP-Design-Patterns-Stephan-Schmidt/dp/389721864X/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1334906032&sr=8-7

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the Singleton approach in PHP all the time and in my opinion, my code isn't a mess - yet. A lot of other projects (e.g. Typo3) use global arrays to store objects. I don't like that approach, as an array item can be easily overwritten.

But if you are using namespaces and order your project files in folders (like in Java), the Singleton approach is pretty clean. And with a `getInstance()` method, you're much more on the safe side than with `$globalArray['myInstance']`.

Comment: Agreed. There is nothing wrong with a factory/singleton pattern for re-using established objects.

Answer (score 0):

In php we use the lazy loading technique used also by important framewokr

You need to build an autoload strategy, because in php you should always include the file in which the class is written to instantiate an object

Symfony uses the namespaces so for example

```
\DB\Repository\Classes\Product
```

for example is registered in a

```
/DB/Repository/Classes/Product.php file
```

and you make directly a

```
$product = new Product()
```

Without taking care of including file and other kind of operations like this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what You're looking for is the Service container (IoC container). There are some PHP implementations out there that You can use in Your application. The one I've used so far is called the Dependency Injection component provided by the Symfony framework. The documentation can be found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html).

There is another implementation available in PHP I'm aware of called Zend DI. It's provided by another big PHP framework since version 2.0, which is still in the beta stage though. Some examples on the Zend DI component can be found [here](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Zend+DI+QuickStart).